# mysql, get total weight of products from based on UUID of category

Tags: php, mysql

I am attempting to aquire the total weight of gear, and the name of the category, based on the category that the gear is listed within.

I have three tables of concern.

'gear' (which holds the information about each piece of gear, including the weight) and it has a UUID and the weight field is called "Weight"

'gear_list' (which holds the name of the category in a field called "Subject" and has its own UUID)

'gear_list_items' (which contains the GearUUID, GearListUUID, CategoryUUID)

What I am able to pass to the php script is the GearListUUID.

So what I am needing here is a way to query and have results such as this:

CategoryName, 268 (weight/grams)
AnotherCategoryName, 485 (weight/grams)
AnotherCategoryName, 1028 (weight/grams)
AnotherCategoryName, 768 (weight/grams)
AnotherCategoryName, 448 (weight/grams)

I suspect I may need to post some schema dump, but if anybody has knowledge of how to do this before I go and post all that, it would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to tell for sure without seeing actual table schemas and sample data but you want something like

```sql
SELECT l.Subject, SUM(g.Weight) Weight
  FROM gear_list l JOIN gear_list_items i
    ON l.GearListUUID = i.GearListUUID JOIN gear g
    ON i.GearUUID = g.GearUUID
-- WHERE l. GearListUUID = ?
 GROUP BY l.Subject
```

Comment: Thanks for helping peter. I got your code working via this, however they are all returning the same weight.
 
 `SELECT l.Subject, SUM( g.Weight ) Weight
        FROM gear_lists l
        JOIN gear_list_items i ON i.GearListGUID = i.GearListGUID
        JOIN gear g ON i.GearGUID = g.GUID
        WHERE i.GearListGUID =  'cc3759d90208b92e2852e4d51ad5bd5f'
        GROUP BY l.Subject
        LIMIT 0 , 30`

Comment: To further help you I need to see schemas and sample data. Can you create a [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) and post a link to it here?

Comment: Do you need more help with your question?